# Get a boolean value from database to checkbox with option to update in .NET MVC using AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I need to do the following table with .NET MVC and AJAX:

The idea is a list with users with the option to lock each of them (i am using the standard identity model):

Email            | Username | LockoutEnabled
user1@domain.com | User1    |      [x]
user2@domain.com | User2    |      [0]
user3@domain.com | User3    |      [0]

For the moment I successfully update the current status in the view from the db to the checkbox using this approach

`<td>
   @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => user.LockoutEnabled)
   </td>`

What i want to do next is:
1. Update the db on the current checkbox status without reloading the page
2. Show a notification on successful DB update from the view (no reload)

This is the controller returning the status

`[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult LockUser(string id, bool status)
    {
       PFMDbContext db = new PFMDbContext();
       db.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Id == id).LockoutEnabled = status;
       db.SaveChanges();
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }`

Comment: You need to update all the users once or when the checkbox state schanges?

Comment: hello. i need to the update a single record on checkbox checke/uncheck

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple job using Ajax.

**Create a ViewModel that will be passed to the view.**

```
public class ApplicationUserViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
}
```

**The controller methods.**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LockUsers()
{
    var db = new PFMDbContext();
    var model = db.Users
        .Select(p => new ApplicationUserViewModel
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Name = p.Name, // Or whatever properties you have
            IsLocked = p.LockoutEnabled
        }).ToList();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LockUser(string id, bool isLocked)
{
   var db = new PFMDbContext();

   try
   {
       var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Id == id);
       user.LockoutEnabled = isLocked;

       db.SaveChanges();
       return Json(true);
   }
   catch
   {
       return Json(false);
   }
}
```

**In your view**

```
@model List<ApplicationUserViewModel>

<!-- This is just an example. Use your own template. -->
@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    <div>
    <p>@user.Name</p>
    <input id="@user.Id" type="checkbox" data-userid="@user.Id" class="js-islocked" value="@user.IsLocked" /> 
    </div>
}
```

**Then using javascript you can bind the select event.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on('change', 'js-islocked', function () {
        var userId = $(this).data('userid');
        var isLocked = $(this).prop('checked');

        // Use ajax to save the modification
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Users/LockUser',                    
            data:{ id: userId, isLocked: isLocked },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success:function(data) {
                // Update a div or show a message
            }                         
        })
    });
});
```